# how to use bluebirdJS promises to make API requests in BATCHES instead of just limiting by concurrency

Tags: promise, batch-processing, bluebird, throttling, rate-limiting

I have 1000 http API requests to be made. I have kept them all as promises in an array. I want to execute them in "***BATCHES" of 100*** at a time - not more than that to avoid hitting any API rate-limit / throttling etc.

While [bluebirdJS](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) provides the `.map()` function with the `concurrency` option what it does is it limits the number of calls made ***AT A TIME***. Meaning it will ensure that no more than 100 concurrent requests are being worked on at a time - as soon as the 1st request resolves, it will begin processing the 101st request - it doesn't wait for all the 100 to resolve first before starting with the next 100.

The "***BATCHING***" behavior i am looking for is to first process the 100 requests, and ***ONLY AFTER*** all of the 100 requests have completed it should begin with the next 100 requests.

Does BlueBirdJS provide any API out of the box to handle batches this way?

Comment: Wouldn't breaking the request in a list of 100 items each and applying a `Promise.all` inside a `Promise.each` do ?

Answer (score 2):

You can split big `urls` array to an array of batches. For each batch run `Promise#map` which will be resolved when *all* async operations are finished. And run these batches in sequence using `Array#reduce`.

```
let readBatch(urls) {
  return Promise.map(url => request(url));
}

let read(urlBatches) {
  return urlBatches.reduce((p, urls) => {
    return p.then(() => readBatch(urls));
  }, Promise.resolve());
}

const BATCH_SIZE = 100;
let urlBatches = [];
for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i+= BATCH_SIZE) {
  let batch = array.slice(i, i + BATCH_SIZE);
  urlBatches.push(batch);
}

read(urlBatches)
   .then(() => { ... }) // will be called when all 1000 urls are processed
```

Comment: nice.... i had used `.mapSeries()` instead of `.reduce` to run through the batches in series.... the code is somewhat cleaner with `.mapSeries()`

Comment: In your question you asked about solution for running a new batch, **ONLY AFTER all of the 100 requests have completed** `Bluebird#mapSeries` works differently. It runs operations in series, not in parallel [docs](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.mapseries.html).

Comment: But that's what we are trying to do, right? To run one batch after another batch in series/sequence - so `Bluebird#mapSeries()` does exactly that as you cited the docs. The promises INSIDE a batch can, however, happen in parallel

Comment: No, it's different. `Array#reduce` runs batches in series, but async operations in _a batch_ in parallel. `Bluebird#mapSeries()`... I don't understand how it can be used to run batches, it can run only async operations in a batch, and only in series.